# Get the sales rep and where they belong

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
    TerritoryId, Description, ParentTerritoryId, Type 
--------------------------------------------------------
    1, UnitedStates, null, Territory 
    1, John Smith, 1, Sales Rep 
    2, Georgia, 1, Territory
    2, Jane Doe, 2, Sales Rep 
    2, Ann Smith, 2, Sales Rep
```

How can I write the following T-SQL? Let's say I'm searching for a name like "Ann Smith".

I'd like the resultset to look like:

```
1, United States, null, Territory
2, Georgia, 1, Territory
2, Ann Smith, 2, Sales Rep
```

Basically, I want to find a sales rep or sales reps and what organization they belong to all the way up the chain.

Comment: Are your "TerritoryId" fields supposed to be unique in the first table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to have a multilevel structure in the table ideally you would want to split your table.

one table for territory and one for sales reps.

If your sales reps can have more than one territory you would need to go to 3 tables
one for sales reps, one for territory, and a lookup table.

if you are going to do a multi level table you need each entry to have a unique id

Comment: Is lookup table synonymous to an association table between sales rep and territories?

Comment: Also, what if my current task is to get the sales reps and territories into a treeview in the ui, would it be better to union them in this particular case? What is best practice?

Comment: The lookup table is an association table showing salesrep ID and Territory ID. normally a join on that would be the way it's done, however I have seen it done all in one table, however the performance was poor and it was a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+ so we can use a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) and assuming the TerritoryId values should really be unique:

```
TerritoryId  Description   ParentTerritoryId  Type 
--------------------------------------------------------
1            UnitedStates  NULL               Territory 
2            John Smith    1                  Sales Rep 
3            Georgia       1                  Territory
4            Jane Doe      3                  Sales Rep 
5            Ann Smith     3                  Sales Rep
```

Then you can do this:

```
WITH cteRecursion AS (
    SELECT TerritoryId, Description, ParentTerritoryId, Type, 1 AS Level
        FROM YourTable 
        WHERE Description = 'Ann Smith'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.TerritoryId, t.Description, t.ParentTerritoryId, t.Type, c.Level + 1
        FROM YourTable t
            INNER JOIN cteRecursion c
                ON t.TerritoryId = c.ParentTerritoryId
)
SELECT TerritoryId, Description, ParentTerritoryId, Type 
    FROM cteRecursion 
    ORDER BY Level DESC;
```